# Question regarding bloch vector solutions for master equation on page 388 of N&C

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, bloch-sphere

On page 388 of N&C, you are asked to find the solution to a differential equation for a two-level atom coupled to a vacuum. However, I have no experience with differential equations, so I am having some difficulty seeing where they get their solutions from. After moving to the interaction picture, I get $$\frac{d\tilde{\rho}}{dt}=\gamma[2\sigma_{-}\tilde{\rho}\sigma_{+}-\sigma_{+}\sigma_{-}\tilde{\rho}-\tilde{\rho}\sigma_{+}\sigma_{-}]$$I get as far as the following after changing $\tilde{\rho}$ to is bloch vector representation:

$$\frac{d\tilde{\rho}}{dt}=\gamma\begin{bmatrix}1-z & \frac{x-iy}{2}\\\frac{x+iy}{2} & -1+z\end{bmatrix}$$

It then asks you to solve the three differential equations associated with the bloch vectors.

I get $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\gamma\lambda_{x}\sigma_{x}$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\gamma\lambda_{y}\sigma_{y}$$ $$\frac{dz}{dt}=\gamma(2 -2\lambda_{z})\sigma_{z}$$

However, the answers given are $$\lambda_{x}=\lambda_{x}(0)e^{-\gamma t}$$ $$\lambda_{y}=\lambda_{y}(0)e^{-\gamma t}$$ $$\lambda_{z}=\lambda_{z}(0)e^{-2\gamma t}+1-e^{-2 \gamma t}$$.

I know using $$\frac{dx}{dt}=Ax(t)\to x=x(0)e^{At}$$

However, A disappears from there exponentials and I am unsure how they arrived at the answer they give for $\lambda_{z}$

Comment: how did you get to your expressions for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ etc?

Comment: By the assumption that, since I can break up the density operators into the linear combination of the identity, along with the pauli matrices weighted by their corresponding vector in the bloch vector, then the dynamics of those variables should only depend on the parts of the density matrix they involve. As I said, I have little to no experience solving these types of equations. Edit: By your question I assume I am completely wrong XD

Comment: I'm saying to spell out explicitly what you did that led you to those equations. Also, $\lambda_i$ are not defined in the post, so it's not clear what calculations you did to get to the expressions you write

Comment: I assume $\lambda_{i}$ refers to the values of the bloch vector. This is all on pg 388. They give $$\frac{d\rho}{dt}= -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,\rho]+\lambda[2\sigma_{-}\rho\sigma_{+}-\sigma_{+}\sigma_{-}\rho-\rho\sigma_{+}\sigma_{-}]$$ Then I move to the interation picture, and proceed from there. I arrived at those differential equations by splitting $\frac{d\tilde{\rho}}{dt}$ into its bloch vector components, which I did by just taking out the vector from the density matrix, and applying it and $\gamma$ to the respective pauli matrices.

Comment: given a 2x2 matrix $A$, you extract its components in the Bloch representation computing $\operatorname{Tr}(A\sigma_i)$ with $\sigma_i$ the Pauli matrices. If you do that on your expression for $\partial_t \tilde \rho$ you get on the RHS something that is a function of $x,y,z$

Comment: Alright I have used the trace and obtained the values of the bloch vector. Howeve I still don't see how the pauli matrices disappear or where the negative value is being introduced in their answers.